# how to add sub categories in a category, in the .json file?

Tags: python

I'm scraping a site with Python, and throwing the results at a `.json‍`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

import requests

url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/infosimples-public/commercia/case/product.html#'

resposta_final = {}

response = requests.get(url)

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
resposta_final['skus'] = [element.get_text(strip=True) for element in parsed_html.select(".skus-area")] 


json_resposta_final = json.dumps(resposta_final)

with open('produto.json','w' ) as arquivo_json:
    arquivo_json.write(json_resposta_final)
```

**produto.json**

```
"skus": [
        "Rubber Duck MK Ultra - Original$ 7.95$ 9.95Rubber Duck MK Ultra - Summer VersionOut of stockRubber Duck MK Ultra - Batman Version$ 14.95"
    ]
```

But I need below format:

```
    "skus": [
{
    "name": "Rubber Duck MK Ultra - Original$ 
            Rubber Duck MK Ultra - Summer
            Rubber Duck MK Ultra - Batman Version"

"current price": "7.95$
                    null
                    $ 14.95"

"old price": "9.95
                null
                null"
                    
"available": "true
                false
                true"
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this if you want to all the details of single product together.

```
for i in parsed_html.select(".card"):
    data = {}
    data["name"] = i.find("sku-name")[0].text.strip()
    data["current_price"] = i.select(".sku-current-price")[0].text.strip() if len(i.select(".sku-current-price")) else None
    data["old_price"] = i.select(".sku-old-price")[0].text.strip() if len(i.select(".sku-old-price")) else None
    data["availability"] = "true" if data.get("current_price") or data.get("old_price") else "false"
    resposta_final.append(data)
```

else just create seperate list of each detail and append it to your response.

Comment: in this code I get the following error:   AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: you have change the resposta_final to a list variable

Answer (score 0):

First, let me suggest that the format you're asking for is not ideal. Instead, consider something like

```
"skus": [
    {"name": "Rubber Duck MK Ultra - Original",
     "current price": "$7.95",
     "old price": "$9.95",
     "available": True
     },
    # ... etc
]
```

This is a list of dicts, with each dict representing a single SKU and containing the desired fields. This is a more natural representation of the data, and it makes it easier to access the information for each SKU.

**UPDATED** (to take into account that the individual fields are available in the parsed HTML).

```
skus = parsed_html.select(".card")

def sku_is_available(sku_tag):
    oos_content = "https://schema.org/OutOfStock"
    if sku_tag.find(content = oos_content) is not None:
        return False
    return True


def text_of_class(css_class, tag):
    '''Helper function to extract desired properties
        from single SKU'''
    try:
        text = tag.select_one(css_class).text
        text = text.strip()
    except: 
        text = None
    return text


def clean_price_string(price_string):
    '''Returns price_string without white spaces'''
    import re
    
    if price_string is not None:
        price_string = re.sub(r'\s+', '', price_string)

    return price_string


def compile_sku_dict(sku_tag):
    '''Takes BS tag of single SKU
        and returns desired properties in dict.'''
    name = text_of_class(".sku-name", sku_tag)
    
    old_price = text_of_class(".sku-old-price", sku_tag)
    old_price = clean_price_string(old_price)
    
    current_price = text_of_class(".sku-current-price", sku_tag)
    current_price = clean_price_string(current_price)
    
    available = sku_is_available(sku_tag)
    
    out = {"name": name,
           "current price": current_price,
           "old price": old_price,
           "available": available
          }
    return out

    

[compile_sku_dict(sku) for sku in skus]
```